# Who is the LaHem ("them") in Mussaf Rosh Chodesh?

Tags: tefilla, rosh-chodesh-new-month, musaf

In Musaf of Rosh Chodesh we say אַהֲבַת עוֹלָם תָּבִיא **לָהֶם** - bring **them** eternal love.

Who is this phrase referring to? Who is the *them* in this supplication?

If it referes to the renewed temple  service, then why doesn't it say "*us*" - bring **us** eternal love.

The chapter starts with the Rosh Chodesh atonement, asking for the altar to be rebuilt, so we can bring the sacrifices, rejoice with the service in the temple and David's songs (Psalms, presumably) and then states *bring **them** eternal love* - and recall the covenant of the fathers for their sons.

Here's the entire piece in Nusach [Ashkenaz](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01774.html#HtmpReportNum0121_L2). The [Rambam](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01999.html#HtmpReportNum0048_L2) and [Edot Hamizrach](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01547.html#HtmpReportNum0068_L2) have almost identical wording.

> רָאשֵׁי חֳדָשִׁים לְעַמְּךָ נָתַתָּ, זְמַן כַּפָּרָה לְכָל תּוֹלְדוֹתָם, בִּהְיוֹתָם מַקְרִיבִים לְפָנֶיךָ זִבְחֵי רָצוֹן, וּשְׂעִירֵי חַטָּאת לְכַפֵּר בַּעֲדָם, זִכָּרוֹן לְכֻלָּם יִהְיוּ, וּתְּשׁוּעַת נַפְשָׁם מִיַּד שׂוֹנֵא. מִזְבֵּחַ חָדָשׁ בְּצִיּוֹן תָּכִין, וְעוֹלַת רֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ נַעֲלֶה עָלָיו, וּשְׂעִירֵי עִזִּים נַעֲשֶׂה בְרָצוֹן, וּבַעֲבוֹדַת בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ נִשְׂמַח כֻּלָּנוּ, וּבְשִׁירֵי דָּוִד עַבְדְּךָ הַנִשְׁמָעִים בְּעִירֶךָ הָאֲמוּרִים לִפְנֵי מִזְבְּחֶךָ. אַהֲבַת עוֹלָם תָּבִיא **לָהֶם**, וּבְרִית אָבוֹת לַבָּנִים תִּזְכּוֹר. ‏

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.dspcsp.com/vye/musafrh.pdf (Hebrew) for all the questions in this paragraph.
Actually this specific question is dismissed as something happening a lot in the Tefilah, a grammar change from "Us" to "Them"

Answer (score 0):

תחילת הפיסקה משתמשת בלשון נסתר או גוף שלישי והכוונה היא לכלל ישראל שהיו בעבר ועבדו במקדש. 
לאחר מכן הלשון משתנה לתפילה לעתיד
נראה שהכוונה במילה "להם" היא למי שיעלה על המזבח עולת ר"ח ושעירי עזים. ‏

The start of the quoted passage uses third person, referring to those Jews who served God in the Temple. Then it switches to future, seemingly implying that "to them" means "to those who *will* serve Him in the Temple".

Comment: Is your first paragraph a quotation from somewhere?